# How to Delete Rows with respect to Last Values via InputBox

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to ask that how to delete rows with respect the last Numeric value by using InputBox.
since the below code is executed without asking the user. I have a request that how it could be possible using input box.

```
Sub DeleteRowsWithLastValue()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim AskNum As Integer
    
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = LastRow To 6 Step -1
        If Right(ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i), 1) <> 1 Then
            Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Thanks & Regards

Muneeb

Comment: The above code execute as it if it is found the last character not equal to "1" without asking user, it will delete all the rows.  I just want it that before deleting the rows it will ask the user to enter any one character between 1 to 9 and if it found it the last character in Range B6 to BLastRow of that cells then it will delete all that relevant rows which it enters it in Input Box. I hope it will concisely clear my query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will ask the user for the number they would like to delete and execute.

```
Sub DeleteRowsWithLastValue()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim AskNum As Integer
    
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    AskNum = InputBox("What number would you like to delete?", "Delete Prompt")
    
    
    For i = LastRow To 6 Step -1
        If Right(ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i), 1) = AskNum Then
            Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I am grateful to Darrell H. Many Thanks to you.

Comment: Maybe worth validating the entry with `If AskNum Like "[0-9]" Then`

Comment: Thanks for Adding the line of code but I would like to ask that can "0" be omitted.

Comment: `If AskNum Like "[1-9]" Then`